# How can I include the red-circled paragraph in the math mode?

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

I am facing a problem when trying to include the following red-circled paragraph like math text under math mode:

[image: Side paragraph math text in math mode]

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prepare two “boxes” to be set flush left and flush right respectively, anchored at their top line.

Some horizontal smashing gives the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{The consumer's problem}

% left box
\noindent$
  \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
    &\textup{Max} && \int_0^T u(c_t)e^{-\rho t}\,dt, \\
    &\textup{subject to\quad}
    &&\dot{b}_t = \gamma b_t +w_t-c_t.  \\
    &\makebox[0pt][l]{Boundary conditions:} \\
    &\makebox[0pt][l]{$\begin{aligned}
      &b(0) = b_0\\
      \textup{and}\quad& b_T e^{-rt} \ge 0 \quad \textup{(No-Ponzi condition)}
     \end{aligned}$}
  \end{alignedat}
$\hfill
% right box
$
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    &u'(c_t)>0,\quad u''(c_t)<0\\
    &\begin{aligned}[t]
       \textup{and}\quad & \smashoperator[l]{\lim_{c\to\infty}} u'(c_t)=0 \\
                         & \smashoperator[l]{\lim_{c\to-\infty}} u'(c_t)=\infty
      \end{aligned} \\ \hline
  \end{aligned}
$\par\medskip

The No-Ponzi condition says that a consumer cannot accumulate unsustainable debt.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Incidentally, Carlo Pietro Giovanni Guglielmo Tebaldo [Ponzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Ponzi), aka Charles Ponzi, just may be the second-most-frequently encounterd Italian name in all of economics. (The most frequently encountered Italian name in all of economcs must surely be that of Vilfredo Federico Damaso [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilfredo_Pareto).)

Comment: @Mico Not the best advertising for Italy… ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? (Not sure I was able to decipher your handwriting entirely correctly... E.g., is it `\gamma` or `r`?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$u'(c_t)>0$, $u''(c_t)<0$}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{The consumer's problem}
\begin{align*}
&\max \int_0^T u(c_t)e^{-\rho t}dt\,, 
\hspace{1in}\text{\smash[b]{%
\parbox[t]{\mylen}{%
    \centering
    $u'(c_t)>0$, $u''(c_t)<0$\\
    \medskip
    and$\begin{aligned}[t]
           \lim_{c\to\infty} u'(c_t) &=0 \\
           \lim_{c\to-\infty}u'(c_t) &=\infty
        \end{aligned}$ 
    \hrule
    }}} \\
\intertext{subject to}
&\dot{b}_t = \gamma b_t +w_t-c_t\,.  \\
\intertext{Boundary conditions:}
&\begin{aligned}
b(0) &= b_0\\
\text{and}\quad b_T e^{-rt} &\ge 0 \quad\text{(No-Ponzi condition)}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
The No-Ponzi condition says that a consumer cannot accumulate unsustainable debt.

\bigskip\noindent
\textbf{Solution}

\dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am having a bit of trouble reading the hand writing so couldn't even work it out from first principles. But I have maybe given you a place to start.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


$u^{'}(c_t)>0,u^{''} (c_t)<0$\\
$\lim{\; u^{'}\to(c_t)}=0$\\
$c \rightarrow \infty$\\
$\lim{\; u^{'}\to(c_t)}=\infty$\\
$c \rightarrow\infty$

\end{document}
```

was not sure if it was c sub t or ct